# Get text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
<input type="checkbox"/>
<span>Foobar</span>
<input type="radio" checked="checked">Foo
<input type="radio">Bar
```

How to get the text `Foo` with jQuery where `$(this)` is the node `<input type="checkbox"/>`?

I can get the `<input type="radio" checked="checked">` with `$(this).parent().find(":checked").not($(this))` but I don't know how to have the text.

Comment: This isn't correctly formed HTML so you might have trouble

Comment: @m.edmondson: What isn't correct in the HTML?

Comment: The <input> aren't closed they should be `<input type="radio" checked="checked" />`Foo or `<input type="radio" checked="checked">Foo</input>` or am I mistaken?

Comment: @m.edmondson: The first example in your comment is only required  for XHTML validation. The second isn't actually valid HTML.

Comment: But it is correct they should be closed?

Comment: Using [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/label) tags together with your inputs will improve usability as well as making it easier to find the text associated with a particular input.

Comment: @m.edmondson: No. Closing it with `<input />` is only an XHTML validation consideration. Closing it with `<input>text</input>` is invalid altogether. Doing `<input>` is perfectly valid HTML, but won't be accepted by XHTML validators.

Comment: I agree - I stand corrected http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4, specifically that `End tag: forbidden`

Comment: @m.edmondson : I copy the code from Firefox with Firebug (right click > copy innerHTML), it didn't put the `slash`.
@mblase75 : I will use the label tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get to the target element...

- use `[0]` to get the DOM element at the first index from the jQuery object,
- use `nextSibling` to get the text node,
- use `data` to extract the text content.

---

```
var txt = $(this).next().next()[0].nextSibling.data
```

or

```
var txt = $(this).nextAll(':radio')[0].nextSibling.data
```

Comment: Ahaha, again. Was just typing this ;)

Comment: I want the text of the checked radio button so I change `:radio` by `:checked` `$(this).nextAll(':checked')[0].nextSibling.data`
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `.val()` might work ([API Reference](http://api.jquery.com/val/)).

```
$(this).parent().find(":checked").not($(this)).val()
```